# Laravel Excel Export doesnt work - Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, excel, laravel, composer-php

I was trying to export my collection and view into excel format by using Maatwebsite Laravel Excel

here is my code

```
public function index(){
    return Excel::download(new AdminExport, 'testa.xlsx');
}
```

and this is my export code

```
public function collection()
{
    return TbDatapribadi::all();
}
```

there is no specific problem in my code right ? but it is always showing error in the maatwebsite excel export function

> Using $this when not in object context

[image: error]

```
public function download($export, string $fileName, string $writerType = null, array $headers = [])
{
    return response()->download(
        $this->export($export, $fileName, $writerType)->getLocalPath(),
        $fileName,
        $headers
    )->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
}
```

i did follow the documentation for installation [laravel excel](https://laravel-excel.com/)

anyone have any suggestion what should i do ?

my php version is 7.4
my laravel version is 8.83

Comment: Can you add the full export class and controller code? Something about the error screams missing or wrong namespace or missing trait on your export class but hard to tell without all of it.

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to Composer, or Excel itself?